# How do I round to 2 decimal places in R? The round() is producing an error each time

Tags: r, dplyr, rounding

I need help with different questions that I have a similar issue with on an assignment. I am required to have my answer rounded to 2 decimal places in R but whenever I use `round()` or `round()%>%as.data.frame()`, it outputs an error.

This is what I tried for different questions:

```r
Q1 <- flights %>%
  group_by(carrier) %>%
  summarize(mean(distance)) %>%
  filter(carrier %in% c("AA", "EV", "FL"))

Q4 <- msleep %>% 
  select(conservation, sleep_total) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  group_by(conservation) %>% 
  summarise(mean_sleep = mean(sleep_total, na.rm = TRUE), 
      var_sleep = var(sleep_total, na.rm = TRUE)) 

Q2 <- fastfood %>% 
  group_by(restaurant = "Subway") %>% 
  summarize(mean = mean(sugar)) 

Q3 <-fastfood %>% 
  group_by(restaurant="Taco Bell") %>% 
  summarize(mean=mean(calories))
```

Each one is producing the right answer, I'm just having trouble rounding to 2 decimal places with `round()` and don't know what else I should do. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm not certain where the question is: you mention the need to use `round()` but none of your code attempts to do so. At least two of those datasets (`flights` and `msleep`, can't find `fastfood`) are mixed-class frames, so you cannot do `%>% round()` (and generally it's not a good way to do that anyway). You mentioned an error, if you want help with an error then you need to include it in your question (please [edit] it in).

Comment: Further, the Stack tag-recommendation system is imperfect. If you mouse-over a tag, it'll often tell you something about it, including when it is _not_ appropriate. Two tags here are not: [tag:rstudio] is about the _IDE_, not any language one might use within it, so that tag is clearly not right; [tag:tidyverse] is about installation or integration of the entire tidyverse library, it also says *"do not use if your question relates to one or two components of the tidyverse"*; your question is _at best_ about [tag:dplyr]. I've edited for you, please QA the recommendations in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to control the number of (significant) digits in your report (i.e. RMarkdown or Quarto render), submit a CSV (or similar) file with rounded values or something else? For reporting, you don't need to alter the values, output can be controlled though table generator of choice (i.e. `knitr::kable()` ). Or by applying `format()` or tibble::num()` to certain columns. Or perhaps something like `options(digits = 5)` is enough here.

Answer (score 0):

You could add `%>% mutate_if(is.numeric, round, 2)` after your code :

```
msleep %>%
  select(conservation, sleep_total) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  group_by(conservation) %>%
  summarise(mean_sleep = mean(sleep_total, na.rm = TRUE),
  var_sleep = var(sleep_total, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, round, 2)

# A tibble: 6 × 3
  conservation mean_sleep var_sleep
  <chr>             <dbl>     <dbl>
1 cd                 2.3       0.32
2 domesticated       7.58     14.5 
3 en                13.0      39.4 
4 lc                11.4      21.8 
5 nt                13.0       3.84
6 vu                 6.93     14.3
```